# How can I prevent foundation watch from adding html <header> stuff to my file?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Using foundation 6. When I have watch running, whenever I make changes to my index.html file, it puts a copy in the dist folder with an added  section. I already have a  and don't need this!
How can I prevent this behaviour?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
  </head>
<body>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SoapMaker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
    <style>
      .bgimage{
        background:url(./assets/img/soapBG2.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"> -->
  </head>
  <body class="bgimage">
```

Comment: Please provide some info about your template file and setup.

Answer (score 0):

Foundation site docs have great examples.
The Layouts folder contains a default.html file with the headers in it.
The Pages folder contains your pages with only content - no header stuff there.
If you look in default.html, you will see after the body tag several panini bracketed files to be included in every page including one called body.
I usually create  header, menu, and footer files that will show on every page.

```
<body>
{{> header}}
{{> mainMenu}}
{{> body}}
{{> footer}}
<script src="{{root}}assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll have a look. Haven't tried panini before (I used to do something similar with php includes).